# Selecting a float in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, database

I am trying to do a `SELECT` match on a table based upon an identifier and a price, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ident`='ident23' AND `price`='101.31';
```

The above returns zero rows, while if you remove the `price='101.31'` bit it returns the correct row.

Doing a...

```
SELECT * FROM `table`;
```

Returns the same row as above and quite clearly states that `price='101.31'`.  Yet select fails to match it.  Changing `=` to `<=` makes it work - but this is not exactly a solution.

Is there a way of casting the MySQL float to 2 digits before the operation is performed on it, thus making the above `SELECT` work (or some other solution)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Casting to a decimal worked for me:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(price AS DECIMAL) = CAST(101.31 AS DECIMAL);
```

However, you may want to consider just making the `price` column a DECIMAL in the first place.  DECIMAL is generally considered to be the best type to use when dealing with monetary values.

Comment: This would look for anything in the Table that has a value of '101'.  You need to change it to 'WHERE CAST(price as DECIMAL(7, 2)) = CAST(101.31 AS DECIMAL(7, 2));

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't work because a float is inherently imprecise.  The actual value is probably something like '101.3100000000001'  You could use ROUND() on it first to round it to 2 places, or better yet use a DECIMAL type instead of a float.

Answer (score 11):

Don't ever use floats for money.

Comment: Where do I get change for the customer from?  (sorry, a bit of shopkeeper humour there :)

Answer (score 9):

Today, I also came across the same situation and get resolved just by using FORMAT function of MySQL, It will return the results that exactly match your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE FORMAT(col,2) = FORMAT(value,2)
```

Explanation: `FORMAT('col name', precision of floating point number)`

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:** SELECT * FROM *table* WHERE *price* **like** *101.31*;

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for solution but finally I did it using my previous php number_format() which came in seeing @hmasif's solution.

Use this and you'll get your float - mysql match:

```
$floatmatch = number_format((float)$yourfloatvariable,5);
```

where 5 is five strings from decimal point. e.g. 7.93643

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps something along these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ident='ident23' AND ABS(price - 101.31) < .01;
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?

```
SELECT * , ROUND( price, 2 ) rounded
FROM table
WHERE ident = 'ident23'
HAVING rounded = 101.31
```