# How to check if space/tab is in front of variable?

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql query:

```
select date, apptemp from weather where apptemp = '20.1';

Empty set (0.05 sec)
```

If I then run:

```
select date, apptemp from weather where apptemp like '%20.1';

+---------------------+---------+
| date                | apptemp |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2014-09-24 15:18:43 |    20.1 |
| 2014-09-24 16:23:41 |    20.1 |
| 2014-09-25 14:08:57 |    20.1 |
+---------------------+---------+
```

I thought it might be due to a space in front of the number but `' 20.1'` or `'  20.1'` does not yield results either.

How can I see what character is in front of the 20.1?

Update: Thanks - I've tried the HEX:

```
mysql> SELECT date, apptemp, HEX(apptemp) FROM weather;
```

huh?

```
+---------------------+---------+--------------+
| date                | apptemp | HEX(apptemp) |
+---------------------+---------+--------------+
| 2014-09-25 14:19:04 |    21.4 | 15           |
| 2014-09-25 14:24:02 |    21.3 | 15           |
| 2014-09-25 14:28:57 |    20.8 | 15           |
| 2014-09-25 14:34:02 |    21.4 | 15           |
| 2014-09-25 14:38:59 |    21.2 | 15           |
+---------------------+---------+--------------+
```

Update 2:

Seems to be something with the . - if I do

```
select date, apptemp from weather where apptemp = '20';
```

It returns the correct data.

"20.1" - does not.

Comment: As you pasted it, it looks like there are 3 spaces. If that's the case, Ed Gibbs' answer should give you 202020 at the start of your string, which should not be confused by the 20 that is in apptemp.

Comment: In this example, `apptemp` doesn't appear to be *variable*. It appears to be an *identifier* for a column in the `weather` table. (It is possible to use a procedure variable in a query, but that would need to be in the context of a MySQL stored program; that doesn't appear to be the case here.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [`HEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) function:

```
SELECT HEX(apptemp) FROM weather;
```

This will show the column's value in hexadecimal. Key hex values to look for are `00` (ASCII NUL), `09` (tab), and `20` (space), though there are a host of other "invisible" values.

It's probably easier to query the column along with its hex value so you can see the plain and geek versions of the value:

```
SELECT apptemp, HEX(apptemp) FROM weather;
```

Comment: You should explain how to interpret the result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hex tip.

Seems its caused because the datatype is a float.

[mysql float data not selecting in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135395/mysql-float-data-not-selecting-in-where-clause)

Set to decimal and its working now.