# Easiest mysql ever. But I can't do it. Where clause isn't working

Tags: mysql

Here is my table when I do `Select * from tempF;`

```
| Timestamp | CurrentF | RecordMinF | RecordMaxF |
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| 21:12:53  |    69.23 |       NULL |       NULL |
| 21:15:53  |     67.9 |       NULL |       NULL |
| 21:16:02  |    68.08 |       NULL |       NULL |
| 21:16:08  |    68.08 |       NULL |       NULL |
| 21:16:14  |    68.08 |       NULL |       NULL |
| 22:37:56  |    68.98 |       NULL |       NULL |
| 22:38:08  |    69.16 |       NULL |       NULL |
| 22:38:14  |    69.34 |       NULL |       NULL |
| 22:38:15  |    69.16 |       NULL |       NULL |
| 22:38:32  |    69.34 |       NULL |       NULL |
```

I'm switching from MSSQL to MySQL so maybe I'm missing something. All I want to do is: `select * from tempF where CurrentF = 67.9;`

It says it returns an empty set but clearly in the table there is a row in the CurrentF column that has the number 67.9

Comment: In your sample data, there is no 69.7, only 67.9

Comment: `67.9` is not the same `69.7`

Comment: sorry that was a syntex error when I was typing this up. Both numbers are the same at 67.9, I've just double checked. I'll edit this

Comment: Try '67.9' just to see if it is char or int or other.

Comment: What data type is the `CurrentF` column?

Comment: I'ts float and that was the reason this was happening. I just posted my solution, thanks

Comment: "What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured this out from another StackOverflow post:

[mysql float data not selecting in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135395/mysql-float-data-not-selecting-in-where-clause)

Here was the best answer that I saw:

> Today, I also came across the same situation and get resolved just by
>   using FORMAT function of MySQL, It will return the results that
>   exactly match your WHERE clause.
>
> `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE FORMAT(col,2) = FORMAT(value,2)`
>
> Explanation:
>
> `FORMAT('col name',precision of floating point number)`
>
> Hope it helps.

So to answer my question, I had to write the query like this:

```
Select * from tempF where format(CurrentF,2) = format(67.9,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

select * from tempF where CurrentF = '67.9';
will work for sure..