# Flask SQLAlchemy filter and filter_by don't work with float values

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing API using Flask, Flask-RESTful, Flask-SQLAlchemy and MySQL. The problem is that `filter()` and `filter_by` don't work at all.

Model:

```
from app import db
from datetime import datetime

class AreaModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'aqi_records'

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    aqi = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        index=False,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False
    )
    latitude = db.Column(
        db.Float,
        index=False,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False
    )
    longitude = db.Column(
        db.Float,
        index=False,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False
    )
    created = db.Column(
        db.DateTime,
        index=False,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False,
        default=datetime.now()
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Area {}>'.format(self._string_coords())

    def _string_coords(self):
        return str(self.latitude) + '-' + str(self.longitude)

    def as_dict(self):
        r = {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}
        r['created'] = str(r['created'])
        return r
```

Resource:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, request
from models import AreaModel

class AreaResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        area_coords = request.args.get('area_coords')

        if not '-' in area_coords:
            return {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid coordinate format'}, 400

        latitude, longitude = area_coords.split('-')
        latitude, longitude = float(latitude), float(longitude)

        area = AreaModel.query.filter_by(latitude=latitude).first() # this is the line with the problem

        if not area:
            return {'code': 404, 'message': 'Area not found'}, 404

        return area.as_dict()
```

When I use `AreaModel.query.all()` I get all records in table. But if I add filter I always get `None` as a result and I can't understand why

Edit 1:
received data (coords) is correct;
type: float

Edit 2:
`.get()` isn't working too

Comment: I _suspect_ it would be better to store lat/long as strings - float values may not reliably round-trip through the querying process.  I tried a quick test using `[1.5, 1.33, 1.625, 1.11, 1.34567]` and only 1.5 and 1.625 were found.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302243/selecting-a-float-in-mysql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135395/mysql-float-data-not-selecting-in-where-clause, for example

Comment: See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: @snakecharmerb would you mind posting your answer as an answer (not a comment), so I can mark it as the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats are tricky to work with, because the literal representation of a float may not correspond exactly to the value used in computations, or stored in a database.  This behaviour is discussed in depth in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).  Specific instances of querying with floats in MySQL can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302243/selecting-a-float-in-mysql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135395/mysql-float-data-not-selecting-in-where-clause).

To work around this problem, the MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html) recommend using the `DECIMAL` type in place of `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.

In this particular case, I think you have choice between using `DECIMAL` (and the Python [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) type) or strings to represent latitudes and longitudes.

- if you intend to perform numerical computations with the values, `DECIMAL` is probably the better choice
- if you are only querying against exact values, you could use store the values as strings.

Here is a short example demonstrating how querying with floats does not always produce expected results:

```python
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import orm

Base = declarative_base()


class FloatTest(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'floattest'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    lat = sa.Column(sa.Float)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(lat={self.lat})'


engine = sa.create_engine('mysql:///test', echo=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)


floats = [1.5, 1.33, 1.625, 1.11, 1.34567]

session = Session()
for v in floats:
    session.add(FloatTest(lat=v))
session.commit()

for v in floats:
    res = session.query(FloatTest).filter(FloatTest.lat == v).first()
    print(v, res)
print()
session.close()
```

Output (SQL logs removed):

```
1.5 FloatTest(lat=1.5)
1.33 None
1.625 FloatTest(lat=1.625)
1.11 None
1.34567 None
```