# Query on Mysql View not Working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I run a very simple query on a view it works with one value and doesn't work with all others. i'm trying to select rows from the view with different index value only index 1.5 return results

The following is a sample of the view table

I have this View easylens

```
select * from easylens

+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
|id |type|design|name|brand|index|color|coating|material|
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
| 1 | sv |aase  |nel |hoya |  1.5|292  |ar     |plastic |
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
| 2 | sv |base  |tel |zeri |  1.5|293  |ar     |plastic |
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
| 3 | sv |case  |fel |essi |  1.5|294  |ar     |plastic |
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
| 4 | sv |dase  |gel |hoya |  1.6|293  |ar     |plastic |
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
| 5 | sv |fase  |rel |essi |  1.6|293  |ar     |plastic |
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
| 6 | sv |gase  |mel |hoya |  1.6|292  |ar     |plastic |
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
```

when I run

```
select * from easylens where `index`=1.5
```

I get

```
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
|id |type|design|name|brand|index|color|coating|material|
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
| 1 | sv |aase  |nel |hoya |  1.5|292  |ar     |plastic |
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
| 2 | sv |base  |tel |zeri |  1.5|293  |ar     |plastic |
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
| 3 | sv |case  |fel |essi |  1.5|294  |ar     |plastic |
+---+----+------+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
```

but when I run

```
select * from easylens where `index`=1.6
```

I get

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0002 sec)
```

Comment: what is data type of `index` field?

Comment: @Sadikhasan index field is float

Comment: Change it to DECIMAL - or it's probably sufficient to define precision and scale in FLOAT - but I'm not sure why

Comment: Check this post may helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567434/mysql-floating-point-comparison-issues

Comment: additional http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302243/selecting-a-float-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perils of float (with undefined precision and scale)

```
SELECT * FROM easylens WHERE `index` = 1.6000000238418578;
+----+------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+---------+----------+
| id | type | design | name | brand | index | color | coating | material |
+----+------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+---------+----------+
|  4 | sv   | dase   | gel  | hoya  |   1.6 |   293 | ar      | plastic  |
|  5 | sv   | fase   | rel  | essi  |   1.6 |   293 | ar      | plastic  |
|  6 | sv   | gase   | mel  | hoya  |   1.6 |   292 | ar      | plastic  |
+----+------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to CAST

```
SELECT * FROM easylens WHERE CAST(`index` as DECIMAL) = CAST(1.6 as DECIMAL);
```

Comment: it is not about the casting as much as it is about specifying length Decimal(M,D) float(M,D) didn't work too