# MySQL Query Not Returning Results With Dual Params

Tags: mysql

The following query returns a set of results that include the result I am looking for (Row 110886 in picture)

```
select * from apple_pricing_matrix where nslocale_country_name_id = 119
```

[[image: Looking for result 110886[1]]

I am trying to retrieve the row 110886 by querying for the nslocale_country_name_id of 119 and the price of 99.99 with the following query

```
select * from apple_pricing_matrix where nslocale_country_name_id = 119 and price=99.99
```

But it is not returning the row as seen in the pic below

[image]

Here our my column definitions

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? This seems really basic... Thank you

Comment: What are the data types of your columns?  Perhaps `price` is actually a string (varchar) and therefore needs to be in single quotes?

Comment: Your query is fine and if the data is what you think it is will produce the result you expect. Perhaps someone changed the price between the 2 queries. Please add your table definition. Also replace * with the column names and see what you get in the price column when you select row110886

Comment: Does only price filter query return any result: `select * from apple_pricing_matrix where price=99.99` ?

Comment: You should use `DECIMAL` type instead of float. Read some answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302243/selecting-a-float-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1302270/4421474

```
SELECT * 
FROM apple_pricing_matrix 
WHERE nslocale_country_name_id = 119
 AND CAST(price AS DECIMAL) = CAST(99.99 AS DECIMAL);
```